# Get Last Version in TFS doesn't download the last version in Version Control

Tags: tfs

I have modified default.aspx. When I use Get Last Version in TFS 2005, it still keeps my local version.

How to really get  last version in Version Control ?

Comment: Again, stupid question: But did you check out default.aspx before you changed it?

Answer (score 4):

Get Specific.  In the dialog box, select "Latest" in the DropDown, then check the two checkboxes to overwrite your local files and get all files.

Comment: I had to ALSO cancel my modifications in another menu to really get the job done which is redundant and so not logical.

Comment: Did you totally delete what you have on your local drive?

Comment: Then perform the Get Specific?

Answer (score 1):

Stupid question but did you apply Visual Studio 2005 SP1 AFTER you installed Team Explorer 2005?

You can [Launch SSW Diagnostics](http://www.ssw.com.au/ssw/Diagnostics/Download/SSWDiagnostics.application) to check as we have run into this issue many times and Windows Update can't check this.

If you want to read about [SSW Diagnostics](http://www.ssw.com.au/ssw/Diagnostics/Default.aspx) you can.